# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable when using request.json()

Tags: python, bottle

Every time I try to get the JSON from a request via request.json() the error 'dict object is not callable' occurs. For example,

```
from bottle import run, request, post

@post('/')
def test():
    data = request.json()

run(host='localhost',port=8080)
```

Using curl to test it,

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"test":"test"}' -X POST http://localhost:8080/
```

This is the output,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\javir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 868, in _handle 
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Users\javir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1748, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "d:/Workspace Universidad/SD-P3/test.py", line 5, in test
    data = request.json()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2020 12:43:42] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 741
```

I'm always having the same error no matter the content. Does anyone knows what could It be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, a "call" happens when you include a `()` after a variable. `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` simply means that `request.json` is a `dict` and cannot be called. Remove the `()` after `request.json`.

```
@post('/')
def test():
    data = request.json
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `data = request.json` instead of `data = request.json()`